# How to debug single Nunit test visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nunit

How can I debug a specific Nunit test from visual studio? I have multiple TestFixtures in different files. Whenever I run a test it always hits other TestFixture's debug point/exception.

Comment: Which version of the NUnit VS Testadapter are you using ?  The latest version is 2.0.

Comment: i am using version 2.0

Answer (score 6):

Install nunit test adapter and you can right click inside a unit test method and click debug tests. You can also use the Test Explorer window.

Comment: I can debug tests. i can debug a single test when there is no debug point set in the other testfixture. but problem is when i debug a test debug point of other testfixture gets hit or if there is an exception.